# Requirements too stringent for singleton homotopy class [X,Y]?

Tags: algebraic-topology, fake-proofs

I recently had a problem:

Show that if $X$ is contractible, and $Y$ is path-connected, show that the homotopy class $[X,Y]$ has a single element.

I have been able to prove this (I think) in a fairly "standard way":

Take $f,g:X \to Y$ and homotopy $F(x,t)$ between $i_x$ and constant function at $x_0$. Then consider the path $\alpha$ from $f(x_0)$ to $g(x_0)$.

Then just define $H:X \times I  \to Y$ by:
$$H(x)= \begin{cases} 
      f(F(x,2t)) & t \in [0,1/2] \\
      \alpha(2t-1) & t \in [1/2,1] 
   \end{cases}$$

I can visually see this a bit. My question then is *why* we even need to define the first part of the homotopy in terms of a constant function? So, what is wrong with the following "proof":

So if we had $x \in X$. Then $f(x)=y_1$ and $g(x)=y_2$. But then for each $x \in X$, there is a unique path $\beta_{x}:I \to Y$ from $y_1$ to $y_1$. Then just define homotopy $H: X \times I \to Y$ by $H(x,t)=\beta_{x}(t)$.

Is the problem that each path cannot be guaranteed to have the same $t$ value? Or instead that each particular path does not apply to all $x \in X$?

In other words: does the desired result necessarily depend on the contractibility of $X$?

This is an aside: is it true that in general, a contractible space has the trivial fundamental group?

Comment: I don't get it. Why is $\beta_x$ unique? Moreover, if you choose such a path from $y_1(x)$ to $y_2(x)$ for each $x$, the resulting homotopy doesn't need to be continuous. It seems like a false proof of the claim "$[X,Y]$ is trivial whenever $Y$ is connected" (which is a nonsense)

Comment: Your function H is not well defined: you cannot pick *one* curve $\alpha $ that works for all x, clearly.

Comment: @PeterFranek $\beta_x$ is not a unique path since it depends on your choice of $x$. But doesn't the path from $f(x_0)$ to $g(x)$ also depend on $x$? [second part of H(x). Can you prove to me that the resulting homotopy need not be continuous?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez are you referring to the first "standard" proof, or the latter "fake proof"?

Comment: @peter, the claim the OP wants to prove, that [X,Y] is a point when X is contractible and Y is path connected is certainly true...

Comment: @AndresMejia Yes, just think of $\mathrm{id} : S^1\to S^1$. Can you use your method to homotop it to a constant map? (You only use connectedness of $Y$ in your proof)

Comment: @andrea, your first "proof", which does not work — as I said, the H there does not make any sense. There is nothing standard about it, really ;-)

Comment: While Peter's comments are not quite related to what you asked, Andres, it is **you** who should prove the H you defined is continuous and not anyone else that it is not (hint: it isn't)

Comment: Wait, isn't it continuous iff $f$ is continuous? By function composition, and then the pasting lemma

Comment: It seems to me that the "first proof" can easily be completed to find a homotopy between $f$ and $g$, but the second "proof" is completely wrong. Or am I missing something, Marianno?

Comment: If it were a map to $g(x_0)$, it would not satisfy the conditions of homotopy for all $x \in X$? Namely that $H(x,1)=g(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to avoid a long discussion, let me clarify this: the first proof is incomplete. Let $\alpha$ is a path from $f(x_0)$ to $g(x_0)$, then your $H$ is a homotopy from $f$ to a constant map $x\mapsto g(x_0)$. On the other hand, $g\circ F$ is another homotopy from $g$ to the constant map $x\mapsto g(x_0)$. Then you use the fact that being homotopic is an equivalence relation.

For the second "trial", you usually cannot pick an arbitrary path $\beta_x(t)$ from $f(x)$ to $g(x)$ for all $x$ and hope that the resulting homotopy $(x,t)\mapsto \beta_x(t)$ will be continuous. Note that you never used the contractibility assumption.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Thank you

Comment: And in terms of the "proof," I assume your counterexample suffices to show that the contractibility assumption is necessary

Comment: It's not necessary. $[X,Y]$ can be trivial also in many other cases. Computing homotopy classes is complicated. But yes, $[S^1, S^1]$ is definitely nontrivial, as you probably know, although $S^1$ is connected. Note that there is no way to connect "every two points in a circle by a path so that the path varies continuously". You get problems with antipodal pairs.